# Result of Array.map is undefined in Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have very confusing behaviour in javascript. The body of HTTP request is `undefined=&undefined=`.

```
var data = [1, 2].map(function(item) {
    return {
        Id: item,
        Quantity: 1
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: "someUrl",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: data
});
```

How can I prevent from losing data? Please advise.

Comment: Can't even figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: Have you put a `console.log` right after your map to confirm that is the issue? If so can you post what your map is actually doing? As is the pseudo `map` should  run no issue.

Comment: @PLAudet, I'm trying to pass this data to the server. I'm waiting to see `[{Id: 1, Quantity: 1}, {Id: 2, Quantity: 1}]` in the body of POST request. But the data is undefined.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are posting `data` with `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header. Check documentation for [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). In this case data passed will be serialized with [$.param](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) method, which if you check documentation does the following:

> Create a serialized representation of an array, a plain object, or a jQuery object suitable for use in a URL query string or Ajax request. In case a jQuery object is passed, it should contain input elements with name/value properties.

And now you know why the data is posted as

> undefined=undefined&undefined=undefined

Finally, if you want to post a JSON payload you can stringify data yourself and add `application/json` content-type:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "someUrl",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});
```

Comment: Thank you for addressing the actual problem

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you was the first with the correct answer.
Thank you for help too.

Answer (score 1):

The `data` attribute in ajax function is not the data returned from the ajax execution. It is the data sent to it.

Use the `success` callback function to manipulate the data returned

```
$.ajax({
    url: "someUrl",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: data,
    success: function(dataReturned) {
       // Do something with dataReturned
    }
});
```

Take a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: If you read my question more closely, you will find that I'm talking about ajax **request** (not a **respose**).

Comment: Then edit your post to explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to *stringify* your `data` object in order for it to be retrievable via `$_POST` at the destination.

```
var data = [1, 2].map(function(item) {
    return {
        Id: item,
        Quantity: 1
    }
});
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: 'someUrl',
    method: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 'data=' + JSON.stringify(data) /** <---- here; add a to retrieve on other end; in this case 'data=' */
});
```

Then to access it within your `someUrl` you can *decode* it using `json_decode()`:

```
$json = json_decode($_POST['data']);
```

Becomes:

```
$json = Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Id] => 1
            [Quantity] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Id] => 2
            [Quantity] => 1
        )

)

echo $json[0]->Id; // 1
```

Comment: Thank you for help so much! It's a very stupid mistake.

Comment: As long as you learn from your mistakes they're never "*stupid*". If you *repeat* your mistakes.. well, that's another story ;)